# trying to output from a nested object called in with $ajax() from a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var elements1;

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.pnathan.com/static/elements.json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            elements1 = data;
        }
    });

alert(elements1.Hydrogen.symbol);

});
```

I don't understand why this isn't working.  Can someone explain where I am making my mistake?  By not working I mean the alert box doesn't pop up when I run this, if I replace the alert with something like "alert('bob');" then it does, so I am not requesting the data correctly somehow, or I am not filling my variable correctly.

Comment: If the alert is not coming up then there is most likely an error. Can you view the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: You can try doing console.log(data) in your sunccess handler to see if you're actually getting what you're expecting.

Comment: Good call, looks like I am not getting info back, guess I should have tested my JSON.